# Primary index is being used, not the one which is on the field present in the where condition

Tags: mysql, index, index-tuning, clustered-index

I have 2 tables, one is **category** table and has below coulmns and has a primary index on `cat_id` column.

`cat_id (primary key),  acc_id, islive`

Another table is **cat_brand** table which has below fields and has the composite primary key on fields `cat_id` and `brand_id` and fk relation on `cat_id` column.

`cat_id brand_id acc_id`

Indexes on **cat_brand** are(cat_id,brand_id) which is primary index and another index on **acc_id** column, which I created for below SQL query.

```
select distinct cat_brand.brand_id 
FROM  category cat  
inner join  cat_brand on cat.cat_id = cat_brand.cat_id 
where cat_brand.acc_id=1 
  and cat.islive in ('true' )  
  and cat.acc_id=1;
```

Using explain query shows me, that above query uses the primary index of table **cat_brand** which is `cat_id,brand_id` while where condition in the SQL query is `cat_brand.acc_id=1` and **cat_brand** has an index on the same field, then why it doesn't use the index on **acc_id** field?

Comment: Show DDL of both tables instead of a description. Show EXPLAIN of the query.

Comment: In addition to the `SHOW CREATE TABLEs`, tell us how big the tables are, and what percentage have the indicated values.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly these composite indexes will speed it up:

```
cat: (acc_id, islive_in, cat_id)
cat_brand: (acc_id, cat_id, brand_id)
```

`SHOW CREATE TABLE` may give more clues as to why the Optimizer picked what it did.